# Creating Sublime Text 3 syntax for obscure language

Tags: sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, sugarcube

There's a coding language called SugarCube designed for use in the Twine engine, which is used for text adventure games. [Here's the Documentation for it](https://www.motoslave.net/sugarcube/2/docs/). I'm not exactly an experienced coder - all I have is a few months in C# making a game in Unity - but I'd like to help a friend with his game, and hopefully writing his code in an editor instead of plaintext will help.

The only kind of code that matters is all marked with double angle brackets. Variables are marked with dollar signs `$exampleVar`and are declared and assigned using
`<<set $exampleVar = "foo">>`.

If and switch statements use closing tags similar to HTML:

```
<<if $exampleVar == "foo">>
   // code 
<</if>>
```

or

```
<<switch $exampleVar>>
<<case "foo">>
   // code
<</switch>>
```

The guides I've found for custom syntax (including official documentation) are either outdated or assume you already know everything about YAML, which I don't. Advice?

Comment: If you're open to using a different editor than Sublime Text, it looks like VSCode and Atom both have plugins for support `.tw` (SugarCube2) Syntax Highlighting.

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks, but now I have a new problem: how do I use it? I downloaded the language server, but I don't know how to activate it and google only tells me how to create my own.

Comment: Unfortunately that's beyond the scope of my knowledge; I was able to google-foo the solution for the syntax-highlighting issue, but as far as actually using that language, I have no idea.